# How to remove ajax when use f:ajax in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf

I use ajax in my web page, then I remove it.

My code:

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Test">
    <f:ajax listener="#{connectionController.testConnect()}" execute="@form" render="msgCon"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton id="btnCreate" type="submit" value="Create" action="#{connectionController.insertConnection(accountController.accLogin.id)}"/>
<h:commandLink styleClass="cmdLink" value="Cancel" onclick="clearConn()"/>
```

But when I run page again, generated code:

```
<input id="form:j_idt49" type="submit" name="form:j_idt49" value="Test" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','@form','form:msgCon');return false">
<input id="form:btnCreate" type="submit" name="form:btnCreate" value="Create">
<a href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'clearConn()','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'form\'),{\'form:j_idt50\':\'form:j_idt50\'},\'\')');return false" class="cmdLink">Cancel</a>
```

Why does the cancel button still have ajax? How to fix it?

Comment: I fail to see where you remove it. And why would you? Never saw this requirement in the last 10 years

Answer (score 2):

That's not ajax. You're confusing "JavaScript" with "Ajax". You're probably also confusing the HTML representation of `<h:commandButton>` with `<h:commandLink>`. Those `jsf.util.chain()` and `mojarra.jsfcljs()` have got nothing to do with ajax. They just make it possible to submit a POST form using a plain link instead of a submit button. In plain HTML it's not possible to submit a POST form using a plain link. That's why those helper scripts are all there.

To experiment further, add `<f:ajax>` inside the `<h:commandLink>`. You'll see that it get a `mojarra.ab()` function call in the generated HTML. This will in turn indeed use ajax. Or, replace `<h:commandLink>` by `<h:commandButton>`. You'll see that there are no helper scripts anymore to submit a form using a plain link.